# Unique Column in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, unique-constraint

I m facing a probem and i don't believe that it can accept a solution so I hope if anyone knows a solution suggest it, please.

I have a column in my table that contains a certain records; some of those records are duplicated and I want to insert some new records into my table, but I wish for the new records to not be duplicated. So, basically I want to control when the data can be duplicated and when not.

I ve tried this but it does not work:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP PRIMARY KEY

ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`S.No`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `PCID_uk` (`PCID`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `USERNAME_uk` (`USERNAME`)
```

Comment: Start by showing us the schema for the existing table please

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example?  A `CREATE TABLE` statement, any `ALTER TABLE` statements, and a set of `INSERT` statements which produce the erroneous result would really help demonstrate what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data. We can't really understand your case clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some of those records are duplicated and I want to insert some new records into my table, but I wish for the new records to not be duplicated

Constraints are meant to guarantee integrity over the whole table, so what you ask for is not not straight forward, but still possible.

The idea is to create a new column with a default value of `1`, and then feed it using `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0). Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, and that you want to enforce partial uniqueness on column `col`, that would look like:

```
alter table mytable add col_rn int default 1;

update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, row_number() over(partition by col order by id) rn
    from mytable
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.col_rn = t.rn;
```

With this set up at hand, you can create the following unique constraint

```
alter table mytable add constraint unique_col_rn unique (col, col_rn);
```

Now you can insert new records in your table, not providing values for `col_rn`, so it defaults to `1`. If a record already exists for `col`, the unique constraint raises an error.

```
insert into mytable (col) values (...);
```